# Can SD be calculated from binned data? How to test non-random groups that are clearly different?

Tags: dataset, standard-deviation

I DON"T have the underlying sample data (but could possibly request it).  We are talking millions of data points (utility customers).  It is actually the full population (not a sample) combed for those customers that were not in one rate class for the entire 2011 year (about 75% pass this threshold).

Since the full data set is highly cumbersome, I received it in highly bracketed form (e.g. x,xxx customers used between 6,000 and 6,100 kWhs for the year, x,xxx customers used between 6,100 and 6,200 kwh).

**1. Can an approximation of standard deviation be calculated using this bracketed data?  Is there a convenient way to do this in Excel?  Fortunately, the brackets are narrow (there may be as many as a thousand).**

I have two utility populations that are not at all like a randomly assigned control and test group for a medicine test.  They are customers who qualify and sign up for a subsidy low income rate and those who don't.  They are by definition, clearly different. The smallest usage difference I experienced was 2%.  Despite what might test as fairly high variance of usage (some poor use a lot and some rich are frugal), given a test of 3 million customers, I predict the difference would test as highly significant.

**2. Is Welch's t-stat the appropriate test for these two populations?**

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to approximate the standard deviation under various assumptions, yes.

It's common to consider the values as being at the center of their range, but this induces a (slight) downward bias on the variance. If the distribution is skewed it will also bias the mean.

If you google for Vardeman's document on *Sheppard’s Correction for Variances and the "Quantization Noise Model"*, you'll get some useful discussion; there are some subtleties.

What do you need the standard deviation for?

If the end category* is unbounded, of course there isn't a center for that one, which presents a problem

*(or end two categories if the variable is unbounded in both directions)

Some people fit densities ([e.g.](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1210/1210.0200.pdf)) and infer quantities like variance from those, which deals better with skewness and handles the end-category issue.

As for a test, note that you'll have quite skewed distributions. The assumptions of the t-test won't hold.

Comment: +1 But, with "millions of data points," it seems highly likely that a t-test *would* be valid, almost regardless of the distribution. The real question here concerns what a t-test would mean when applied to "the full population (not a sample)."